# Uploading a file: Unable to write data to the transport connection

Tags: c#, .net, file-upload, upload, httpwebrequest

I am using the following code to upload a file to a CE webserver (IIS).  The server code is 100% robust. It intermittently works on some machines or some target WinCE boxes.  When it fails it throws the following error message instantly. Any advice would be great thanks!

Error

> {System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.InternalWrite(Boolean async, Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size)    at MUSU.HTTPExtensions.UploadFileEx(String uploadfile, String
>   url, String fileFormName, String contenttype, NameValueCollection
>   querystring, NetworkCredential credentials)

Code

```
public static void UploadFileEx(String uploadfile, String url,
                    String fileFormName, String contenttype, NameValueCollection querystring,
                    NetworkCredential credentials)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileFormName))
        fileFormName = "file";

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contenttype))
        contenttype = "application/octet-stream";

    String postdata = "";

    if (querystring != null)
    {
        if (url.Contains("?")) { postdata = "&"; }
        else { postdata = "?"; }

        foreach (String key in querystring.Keys)
        {
            postdata += key + "=" + querystring.Get(key) + "&";
        }
    }
    Uri uri = new Uri(url + postdata);

    String boundary = "----------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    if (credentials != null)
        webrequest.Credentials = credentials;
    webrequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    webrequest.Method = "POST";
    webrequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    //webrequest.KeepAlive = false;

    /// Build up the post message header

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("--");
    sb.Append(boundary);
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"");
    sb.Append(fileFormName);
    sb.Append("\"; filename=\"");
    sb.Append(Path.GetFileName(uploadfile));
    sb.Append("\"");
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    sb.Append("Content-Type: ");
    sb.Append(contenttype);
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    sb.Append("\r\n");

    String postHeader = sb.ToString();
    byte[] postHeaderBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postHeader);

    // Build the trailing boundary string as a byte array

    // ensuring the boundary appears on a line by itself

    byte[] boundaryBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(uploadfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        long length = postHeaderBytes.Length + fileStream.Length + boundaryBytes.Length;
        webrequest.ContentLength = length;

        using (Stream requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            // Write out our post header
            requestStream.Write(postHeaderBytes, 0, postHeaderBytes.Length);

            // Write out the file contents
            byte[] buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)fileStream.Length))];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            /// Write out the trailing boundary
            requestStream.Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
            WebResponse response = webrequest.GetResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a stab in the dark but are you exceeding a request size limit you've set in your .config?

Comment: What .config? My backend is written in C++ and works fine when receiving files from a webform.

Comment: web.config. I'm C# but it looks like you are using ASP.NET?

Comment: This is a Winforms C# app that is posting a file directly to an ISAPI plugin I wrote in C++ - the plugin 100% works

Comment: Check this one out <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186355/unable-to-write-data-to-the-transport-vs2017-asp-net-core-scaffolding-mssql-w/43192121?noredirect=1#comment73467667_43192121>?