# Unable to write data to the transport. Vs2017 ASP.net core Scaffolding ( MSSQL WINDOW 10)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, scaffolding

I am trying to create a controller by scaffolding. But I receive this error

> There was an error running the selected code generator. Unable to write data to the transport.An established connection was aborted by software in your host machine

I am using ASP.NET CORE, Visual studio 2017, SqlServer, Window 10

For days now I am tring to solve this problem with no lucky

Can anyone help?

Comment: Turn off the firewall/antivirus  and try it again.

Comment: I tried turning off the firewall and antivirus with no luck

Comment: I ran vs as administrator still did it solve

Comment: I am using built in window 10 antvirus  Defender

Answer (score 2):

After a long  suffering I was able  to identify the problem

Firewall/antivirus or any network filtering app could be the problem.

My problem was  caused  by ***

> k9 web protection

---

Comment: Yeah... glad about that. this is what i meant to say. +1